# How to format floating-point numbers in a dictionary to remove trailing and leading zeros in Python?

Tags: python, python-re

I have a dictionary in Python with floating-point values like this:

```
{'0': 0.773, '1': -0.529, '2': -0.004, '3': -0.035}
```

I want to format the values in the dictionary to remove unnecessary trailing zeros and leading zeros before the decimal point. For example, I want the output to be:

```
{'0':.773,'1':-.529,'2':-.004,'3':-.035}
```

How can i do it with re (or any way else)?

I want to save the data in a text file and i want to save as much space as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually care what the values look like in the dictionary?  Or do you really only care about how the values appear in the text file?

Comment: In text file, i want it as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern Python won't stringify `float`s with extra trailing zeroes (the only trailing zero it will ever include is the single `0` after the decimal point for whole numbers), so that problem is already handled.

To get from the natural `repr` of a `dict` of this form to the form you said you wanted, just perform a couple `replace`ments:

```
s = {'0': 0.773, '1': -0.529, '2': -0.004, '3': -0.035}
print(repr(s).replace('0.','.').replace(': ', ':'))
```

which outputs:

```
{'0':.773, '1':-.529, '2':-.004, '3':-.035}
```

If the `float`s might be outside the range `-1.0` to `1.0`, you'll need a slight tweak so `10.0` won't become `1.0`:

```
print(repr(s).replace(' 0.','.').replace('-0.','-.').replace(': ', ':'))
```

This obviously won't work properly for a `dict` with arbitrary data (e.g. if it has string keys or values that happen to contain `0.` or `:` ), but for the example, it works just fine, no regex required.